# How to use Ubuntu entirely in Swedish?

Tags: language-support, interface

Just installed 12.04 and when installing I choose my native language (Swedish), but not everything is written in Swedish. For example: "create new folder", "home folder", "system settings" and so on. How do I make it entirely Swedish?

Comment: Have you tried running "language support" from the system settings?

Comment: It probably means that Ubuntu has not been fully translated into Swedish yet. Perhaps you could help Ubuntu get fully translated?

Answer (score 1):

### Fixing lang packs for your applications

If you want to find language packs that are missing from your applications, try this

```
sudo apt-get install $(check-language-support)
```

but the command above will try to fix missing lang packages for all the languages, if you just want to fix this when targeting just 1 specific language

```
sudo apt-get install $(check-language-support --language=sv)
```

### Installing a new language pack for Ubuntu / for your OS / globally

```
sudo /usr/share/locales/install-language-pack sv_SE
```

after that reconfigure your locales with

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

or you can simply run

```
sudo apt-get install language-pack-sv
```

### How to set and manage your locale

please refer to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale/